# How to compare data between MYSQL and PostgreSQL table?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, testing, migration

A database of MYSQL is migrated to Postgres. I need to check whether all the data records have been transferred correctly. Is there a way I can compare the contents of the two tables residing in two different RDBMS?

Comment: Export the table from both servers to text files of the same specification and definite rows ordering. Compare.

Comment: You can use [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw) and compare each table one by one using a generic sql. Most probably, the operation will be slow